# Get closing stock prices for yesterday for multiple stocks

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops, quandl

I'm trying to get yesterday's closing stock prices for all stocks listed on the BSE using https://www.quandl.com/data/BSE-Bombay-Stock-Exchange as the data source. I have a list of company codes that I can use to pull that data but I need to figure out how to iterate over it correctly.

According to the quandl documentation, I can use `quandl.get('BSE/BOM500002', column_index = '4', start_date='2019-03-19', end_date='2019-03-20')` to get yesterday's closing price for a stock where `BOM500002` would be the company code. If my list of company codes is listed in `companyCodes['code']`, could you help me figure out how to generate the company code dynamically to get yesterday's closing stock prices for all stocks listed on this exchange?

Bonus Question: How would I list the name of the stock next to the closing price?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is way to get date name together with the results:

```
import quandl

df = pd.DataFrame([("BOM500002", "ABB India Limited"),("BOM500003", "AEGIS")], columns=["Code", "Name"])


results = []
for i, r in df.iterrows():
    result = quandl.get('BSE/'+r["Code"], column_index = '4', start_date='2019-03-19', end_date='2019-03-20')
    result["Name"] = r["Name"]
    results.append(result)

final = pd.concat(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.

```
import quandl
quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = 'your quandl code'

stocks = [
    'BSE/BOM533171', 
    'BSE/BOM500002'
]
mydata = quandl.get(stocks, start_date = '2019-03-19', end_date='2019-03-21')

mydata.loc[:,(mydata.columns.str.contains('Close'))].T
```

Comment: thanks! is there a way to get stock names with this?

Comment: I would get the data from here and then map to the symbols in you dataframe.  https://www.bseindia.com/corporates/List_Scrips.aspx.